# Creating RPM on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I downloaded one of our application which is bundled as an rpm package. I have to update a specific file inside that rpm package. So I extracted the RPM on my Mac using `tar xvf rpm_package.rpm` .I updated one file after extraction, is there a simple way I can package this again as an RPM.

Answer (score 0):

Not this way.

You can do that if you have access to src.rpm. Then you can unpack the src.rpm. Alter it (https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#packaging-software is your friend). Run rpmbuild (here is how to get rpmbuild to Mac http://timperrett.com/2014/03/23/enabling-rpmbuild-on-mac-osx/ )